# How to create an instance of a generic class with its builder?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, refactoring, lombok

I am writing some code where I have many `Child...` classes which inherit a `Parent` class like `ChildA`, `ChildB`, etc. I am using Lombok's [`@SuperBuilder` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) to generate builders for all these classes. The code looks something like this -

`Parent.java`

```java
package test;

import java.util.Random;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class Parent {
    protected int parentVariable;
    protected Random random;

    Parent() {
        random = new Random();
    }
}
```

`ChildA.java`

```java
package test;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    private int childAInteger;
    private String childAString;

    public ChildA execute() {
        int someInteger = random.nextInt(10);
        return buildResponse(someInteger);
    }

    private static ChildA buildResponse(int someInteger) {
        if (someInteger == 1) {
            return ChildA.builder().childAInteger(0).childAString("").build();
        }
        return ChildA.builder().parentVariable(1).build();
    }
}
```

`ChildB.java`

```java
package test;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class ChildB extends Parent {
    private float childBFloat;
    private long childBLong;

    public ChildB execute() {
        int someInteger = random.nextInt(10);
        return buildResponse(someInteger);
    }

    private static ChildB buildResponse(int someInteger) {
        if (someInteger == 1) {
            return ChildB.builder().childBFloat(0.0F).childBLong(0L).build();
        }
        return ChildB.builder().parentVariable(1).build();
    }
}
```

As you can see the `buildResponse` method has some duplicate code in the `Child...` classes. Since, I have many `Child...` classes this duplication is adding up.

I am trying to refactor this code such that I move the common portion of the `buildResponse` method into the `Parent` class and supply a method to it to run the unique part of its code for all `Child...` classes.

Something like this -

`Parent.java`

```java
package test;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class Parent {
    protected int parentVariable;
    protected Random random;

    Parent() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    protected static <T extends Parent> T buildResponse(int someInteger, Supplier<T> supplier) {
        if (someInteger == 1) {
            return supplier.get();
        }
        return T.builder().parentVariable(1).build();
    }
}
```

`ChildA.java`

```java
package test;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
public class ChildA extends Parent {
    private int childAInteger;
    private String childAString;

    public ChildA execute() {
        int someInteger = random.nextInt(10);
        return buildResponse(someInteger, ChildA::buildChildA);
    }

    private static ChildA buildChildA() {
        return ChildA.builder().childAInteger(0).childAString("").build();
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `return T.builder().parentVariable(1).build();` line in `Parent` class is incorrect. My question is how do I make this work? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if the generated `ParentBuilder` is a superclass of the `ChildBuilder`s? If it is, you could pass in `ChildX::builder` in addition to the `buildChildX` reference, and use that instead of your `T.builder()`. If not,you're out of luck: There is no relation between those `parentVariable` methods, and you'll have to call each of them in the subclasses.

Comment: I believe Jorn's suggestion will work, but if we have the param as `Parent.ParentBuilder<?, ?>`, it will require an unchecked cast. Not sure if we can somehow model the builder with the type `T`.

Comment: If the second type parameter is `TB extends Parent.ParentBuilder<T, TB>`, it works without a cast.

Comment: @Jorn @Thiyagu @Jan Rieke, I didn't get how to use this suggestion. I tried modifying `buildResponse` method with `protected static <T extends Parent, TB> T buildResponse(int someInteger, Supplier<T> supplier, Supplier<TB extends Parent.ParentBuilder<T, TB>> parentSupplier) {` but this doesn't work. There's a syntax error on "extends" at `<TB extends Parent.ParentBuilder<T, TB>>`.

Comment: Major brainfart. Please ignore the previous comment. The correct syntax is - `protected static <T extends Parent, TB extends Parent.ParentBuilder<T, TB>> T buildResponse(int someInteger,Supplier<T> supplier, Supplier<TB> parentSupplier) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this if you use composition over inheritance:

```
@Builder
@Getter
class Parent {
  // parent fields
}

@Builder
@Getter
class ChildA {
  // @Delegate or something? I'm pretty sure Lombok can do that too.
  Parent parent; // supply this using `ParentBuilder`
  // other fields
}
```